# In dub, how do I set a custom optimization level to only certain files?

Tags: d, dub

I have some files that are several megabytes generated code. I would like to compile those files only with optimization level 0, and all other files with optimization level 3. How would I specify this in dub?

If the generated code files compile at -O3, they never finish compiling.

Comment: My advise - stick to the good-old Make...

Comment: I was using make, but then I had to use botan which is much easier to build with dub.

Comment: dub works very well for basic projects, but once you start to get fancier about what you're doing, it starts getting difficult to do with dub if it's possible at all. The fact that it tries to make the typical stuff simple for you (e.g. figuring out the list of files to build for you) tends to get in the way of the cases where you do need to specify stuff in greater detail. In general though, I'd advise trying to use dub (since it's easier to interact with other D projects that way) and only doing something else when dub really isn't going to work. And dub will likely improve over time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

dub is not set up to have you list specific files. It pulls in every file in whatever source directories you set. As such, it really isn't set up to have some files compiled one way and some another. However, you could always create a sub-package just for those files, and have its dub configuration set with flags to optimize it differently. However, at that point, it is technically a separate library, so your actual code has to be organized in a way for that separation to work.